# Polish characters in mysql response

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with polish characters. I can't get correctly written words, like '?ukasz' instead of "Łukasz" or even "null", when it supposed to be "Kraków". I tried "mysql_set_charset('utf-8'/'iso-8859-1')" after mysql_connect or iconv(on json_encode($output)) and it's still the same (except now there is "Krak\u00f3" instead of "null"). I'll appreciate any help.

This is a php file for my Android app:

```
$id_client = $_REQUEST['id_klienta'];
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('courier_helper') or die(mysql_error());

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE id_klienta='$id_client'");
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$r;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Read http://kunststube.net/frontback/ and http://kunststube.net/encoding/ and you will not only find out why, but learn something important

Comment: I forgot to add, don't use mysql_* functions anymore, they are deprecated! Switch to PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe problem lies in database. I surrendered and changed pl chars to latin for now, because I've not much time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure, that you are using UTF-8 everywhere:

- script file encoding (UTF-8 instead of ANSI) - you can set encoding it in Notepad++
- html code (meta charset)
- database table charset (when you are creating table or database)
- database `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection_obj);`
- database `SET NAMES utf8` - run that SQL command after connecting

And one more thing - get familiar with PDO. This is my PDO connect function I use:

```
function DbConnect()
{
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "database_name";
    $db_user = "your_username";
    $db_pass = "your_passwd";

    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name; charset=UTF-8", $db_user, $db_pass);
    $link->exec("set names utf8;");
    return $link;       
}
```

You can use that function like this (this is PDO example):

```
    $link = DbConnect();

    $query = $link->prepare("SELECT id FROM wp_users");

    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I tried all you guys have posted, but it still doesn't work. I wrote "echo mysql_client_encoding()" right after "$link = DbConnect()" and it gives me "latin1".

Comment: @user1547938 because this is PDO, not mysql_ extension and you are getting default value from uninitialized, unused mysql object. PDO is completely diffrent.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your database storing data as UTF8, which means converting your existing tables.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

You also need to make sure your connection to the database is UTF8. You can make sure of that by running a SET NAMES query right after your connect.

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

As others mentioned, you should start using PDO.